# Maven command is not able to find any tests

Tags: maven, junit, cucumber, pom.xml, cucumber-java

My tests are running fine with cucumber 6(after changing cucumber version) but with cucumber 4 it is not detecting any tests. just giving output:
Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.243 sec - in PfgApiAutomation.RunCucumberTest

```
Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO]
------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS [INFO]
------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Total time:  2.089 s [INFO] Finished at: 2020-12-09T19:25:55+05:30 [INFO]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have tried every possible page on stackoverflow and haven't found any solution for the same. I'm attaching my pom.xml file for reference.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>PfgApiAutomation</groupId>
    <artifactId>PfgApiAutomation</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <cucumber.version>4.7.4</cucumber.version>
        <junit.version>4.13</junit.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <extent.version>5.0.1</extent.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
            <version>${extent.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.rest-assured/rest-assured -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-configuration2</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Cucumber Extent Reporter -->
        <!--        <dependency>-->
        <!--            <groupId>tech.grasshopper</groupId>-->
        <!--            <artifactId>extentreports-cucumber6-adapter</artifactId>-->
        <!--            <version>2.4.0</version>-->
        <!--        </dependency>-->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

My project structure is as follows:
[image: Project structure is:]

Comment: If I'm correctly informed cucumber-java uses JUnit Jupiter which will execute JUnit 4 tests via vintage engine that means you have to use maven-surefire-plugin version 2.22.2 and newer ...

Comment: By any chance if possible can you please share the complete names of dependencies I need to add In my pom.xml?

Comment: First step is to upgrade the version of maven-surefire-plugin in your pom ....

Comment: Make sure to use the same version for all Cucumber dependencies (and remove the info.cukes one). Also, I'm not sure JUnit 4.13 or v5 are supported; try 4.12?

Comment: @Marit i tried both of your suggestions but it is still not detecting tests.